# R package to connect to bq?

Tags: r, google-bigquery

I'm curious if anyone knows of an R package capable of connecting to bq.
I haven't found anything in CRAN, and the one in {p} seems to be very much outdated.

Comment: https://github.com/hadley/bigrquery also https://github.com/hadley/dplyr may be interesting for you.

Answer (score 1):

As Daroczig says, https://github.com/hadley/bigrquery is the answer.

I didn't know about the more general https://github.com/hadley/dplyr, looks good!